# How to retrieve objects with different names from the same url using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit in order to retrieve the data from an API. This is the url http://mindicador.cl/api and I need to retrieve the objects with the name of "uf", "dolar", "euro" and "utm", all those four in one call. This is my Java class based on the json.

```
public class IEconomicoAPI {
    private String version;
    private String autor;
    private String fecha;
    @SerializedName(value = "uf", alternate = {"dolar", "euro", "utm"})
    private IEconomicoObject uf;

    /* All Getter and Setter methods */
}
```

And this is my call method to retrieve the data which is not working right now.

```
void call() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(MiIndicadorAPI.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        MiIndicadorAPI api = retrofit.create(MiIndicadorAPI.class);

        final Call<IEconomicoAPI> iEconomicoAPICall = api.getAPI();
        iEconomicoAPICall.enqueue(new Callback<IEconomicoAPI>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<IEconomicoAPI> call, Response<IEconomicoAPI> response) {
                String codigo = response.body().getUf().getCodigo();
                if (codigo.equals("uf")) {
                    Log.e("info", "nombre: " + response.body().getUf().getNombre());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<IEconomicoAPI> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I was thinking in a solution which is create 4 objects (one for uf, dolar, euro and utm) but I think is redundant because all these objects have the same fields and the more convenient way should be create just one object. Anyway I hope you orient me about how to resolve this issue. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 4 different variables

```
private IEconomicoObject uf;
private IEconomicoObject dollar;
private IEconomicoObject euro;
private IEconomicoObject utm;
```

But ideally I would suggest changing the API response to something like this

```
{
    "version": "1.5.0",
    "autor": "mindicador.cl",
    "fecha": "2018-04-08T21:00:00.000Z",
    "iEconomicoList": [
        {
            "codigo": "uf",
            "nombre": "Unidad de fomento (UF)",
            "unidad_medida": "Pesos",
            "fecha": "2018-04-08T04:00:00.000Z",
            "valor": 26966.89
        },{
            "codigo": "ivp",
            "nombre": "Indice de valor promedio (IVP)",
            "unidad_medida": "Pesos",
            "fecha": "2018-04-08T04:00:00.000Z",
            "valor": 28088.63
        }
    ]
}
```

in which case the model can be

```
public class IEconomicoAPI {
    private String version;
    private String autor;
    private String fecha;
    private List<IEconomicoObject> iEconomicoList;;

    /* All Getter and Setter methods */
}
```